# mysql query need some loop or array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need help with a mysql query.
I have several products with the same order_id and then want to show everyone but it only shows one product of 30 products.

```
if (!$_GET['orderid']) {

   } 
else
{
    $order_id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['orderid']); // filter everything but numbers for security
}

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tabell_order_product WHERE order_id='$order_id'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $product_id = $row["product_id"];

} 
mysqli_free_result($query); 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tabell_product WHERE product_id='$product_id'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $model = $row["model"];
    $location = $row["location"];
} 
mysqli_free_result($query); 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tabell_product_description WHERE product_id='$product_id'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $name = $row["name"];
} 
mysqli_free_result($query); 
$output .= '<tr>
    <td>' . $product_id . '</td>
    <td>' . $name . '</td>
    <td>' . $model . '</td>
    <td>' . $location . '</td>
  </tr>';?>
```

Comment: You should seriously look up a join for your query. That way, you can minimize all of your queries.

Comment: Cant you use foreach for it?

Comment: Your product_id, model, location and name will only hold the last row from the database, you are overwriting them in every while loop.

Comment: You should either move the logic to make the html table inside the while loop or retrieve values in an array and use another loop

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling `three queries` if it can be done in a `single query`

Try this,

```
<?php
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT t2.product_id,t2.name,t3.model,t3.location FROM
       tabell_order_product t1, tabell_product t2, tabell_product_description t3 
       WHERE t1.order_id='$order_id' AND t2.product_id=t3.product_id"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
        $product_id=$row['product_id'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $model=$row['model'];
        $location=$row['location'];
        $output .= '<tr>
            <td>' . $product_id . '</td>
            <td>' . $name . '</td>
            <td>' . $model . '</td>
            <td>' . $location . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
?>
```

Read [mysqli-fetch-array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Thanks, precisly what i needed :) i didn't know how to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $product_id = $row["product_id"];
} 
var_dump($product_id);
```

above will only get the last product_id of the 30 product_ids，i guess you mean push them into an array like this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $product_id[] = $row["product_id"];
} 
var_dump($product_id);
```

and you have the some errors in the follow code, try to fix them in this way